# Open Graph в битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс, opengraph

Всем привет! У меня при шаринге статьи не выводится картинка детального изображения. Что я делаю не так?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?$APPLICATION->ShowTitle()?></title>
      <meta property="og:image" content="http://' . SITE_SERVER_NAME . $arResult['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['SRC'] . '">
        <?$APPLICATION->ShowHead();?>
        <?$APPLICATION->ShowProperty('og-image');?>
        <?$APPLICATION->ShowHeadStrings('<meta property="og:image" content="http://<?=SITE_SERVER_NAME?>' . $arResult["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]["SRC"] . '" />')?> 
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous">      </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/verstka/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/verstka/assets/css/style.css">
        <!--[if IE]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH?>/verstka/assets/css/fixIE.css"/>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
```

в result_modifier.php я вписываю:

```html
<?if (!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED !== true) die();

$cp = $this->__component;
if( is_object($cp) )
    $cp->SetResultCacheKeys( array('DETAIL_PICTURE') );

?>
```

и в component_epilog.php вывожу:

```html
<?if(!defined("B_PROLOG_INCLUDED") || B_PROLOG_INCLUDED!==true)die();

$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty('og-image', '<met a property="og:image"' . $arResult['DETAIL_PICTURE']['SRC'] . '">');

?>
```

[image: console]

Comment: используйте дебагер для обнаружения проблем  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/

Comment: @Arsen, отладчик выдал - 'Свойство «og:image» должно быть указано в явном порядке, даже если его значение может быть вычислено на основании других тегов.' Я так понимаю при шаринге картинка просто не подхватывается. Как тогда задать изображение явно?

Comment: Если бы вы показали так же source страницы браузера, будет возможность легче вам помочь.

Comment: @Arsen, прикрепил.

Comment: во-первых дебаггер кэширует превью и показывает то, что было в первый раз, если ссылка не изменилась; во-вторых - смотрите другие ошибки в дебаггере, скорее всего там будет ошибка типа "невозможно установить соединение с хостом" по вашему линку

Comment: ну вы даете... забыли `<?php`

Comment: Опять некропостинг... @Духсообщества, зачем поднимаете такие сообщения?

Comment: @TotalPusher: Дух сообщества бот, и просто поднимает время от времени те вопросы, которые посчитал хорошими. :)

Answer (score 1):

Думаю проблема в том что битрикс не выводит доменное имя из переменой, попробуйте в ручную вписать полный путь до картинки и ещё раз проверить дебагером

`<meta property="og:image" content="http://vashsite.ru/images/share.jpg">`

так же я заметил что ваша переменная `$arResult['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['SRC']` показывает в сорсе как текст!! может надо просто сделать echo в `PHP`

```
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $arResult['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['SRC']; ?>">
```

Comment: <meta property="og-image" content="http:///upload/iblock/1ec/1ec4b381e7b0aa420a9133f0c4571ba4.jpg">  
Поюзал отладчиком - он все равно вывел что не видит свойство.
<meta property="og-image" content="<?php echo $arResult['PREVIEW_PICTURE']['SRC']; ?>">  - а при такой правке - выводит в source пустоту.

Comment: вы некорректно вставляете переменную, поэтому для проверки в ручную вставте в header  <meta property="og:image" content="http://vashsite.ru/upload/iblock/1ec/1ec4b381e7b0aa420a9133f0c‌​4571ba4.jpg">   и не забудьте поменять vashsite.ru на ваш реальный домен

Comment: Спасибо Вам за разъяснение! 
Ввел вручную в head - но он все равно выводит что не видит изображение. При шаринге тоже ничего не тянется. Скорее всего да, где то прописал переменную неверно - но вот где - ума не приложу.

Comment: если введёный путь до файла корректен и её можете открыть в браузере.. то возможно в дебагере пока показывает старую версию скана сайта, надо ещё раз провести тестировку

Comment: Приложите свежий исходный код сайта, чтобы понять, правильно ли вы всё сделали.